# Custom char order

Tags: c#, enums

I want to sort a list of codes (two chars) by a custom order. I thought about an enum :

```
    public static enum AlphaCode
    {
        Q, N, A, C
    }
```

I have a list of codes that I want to sort by this order.

`List<string> Codes = new List<string>() { "qc", "aq", "nc", "ac" };`
I want them to be in order as the `AlphaCode`, so they will be output like this :

`qc
 nc
 aq
 ac`

I've listed only some letters, but the `AlphaCode` will contain all alphabetic letters in a particular order with, also, some special characters (like dot, comma, semi-colon, brackets). So maybe the enum is not a good choice.

Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: it looks like you want to not only sort the first character of the code, but all characters by this enum, correct? That is why `aq` comes before `ac`?

Comment: Exactly. I want sort of customized OrderBy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to include non-alpha characters in your custom sort order, it might make more sense to use a collection type instead of an `enum` to store the order. If you used a `List` or an `Array`, for example, you could simply use the index as the key for sorting.

Then, to enable the custom sorting, you could write a method that takes in two strings and returns an int that defines which string comes first, and this can be passed to the `Sort` method of the `List`. The method should take two strings and return `-1` if the first string is "less than" the second, `0` if they are equal, or `1` if the first string is "greater than" the second.

Here's an example of a custom compare method for your codes:

```
private static int CodeComparer(string first, string second)
{
    // Short-circuit if one or both strings are null
    if (first == null) return (second == null) ? 0 : -1;
    if (second == null) return 1;

    // The following list should contain all characters in their desired sort order.
    // NOTE: You will need to include UPPERCASE characters as well if expected.
    //    If you want to treat UPPER CASE the same as lower case, then you would call 
    //    ToLower on first and second, and just have lower case characters in this list.
    var sortOrder = new List<char> { 'q', 'n', 'a', 'c', '-', '3', '2', '1' };

    // Since we will loop through both strings one character at a time,
    // we need to get the length of the shorter string (to prevent index out of range)
    int shortestLength = Math.Min(first.Length, second.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < shortestLength; i++)
    {
        if (first[i] != second[i])
        {
            // When we find two characters that don't match, return the 
            // comparison of their respective indexes in our master list
            return sortOrder.IndexOf(first[i]).CompareTo(sortOrder.IndexOf(second[i]));
        }
    }

    // If all the characters matched, compare the length of the strings. 
    // Normally the shortest comes first, so we do second.CompareTo(first)
    return second.Length.CompareTo(first.Length);
}
```

Now you can use this class pretty easily:

```
private static void Main()
{            
    var codes = new List<string>() { "qc", "aq", "nc", "ac", "1a", "3c", "-n" };

    codes.Sort(CodeComparer);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", codes));
}
```

Output:

> qc, nc, aq, ac, -n, 3c, 1a